# Authentication of user on local app with local database when credentials are stored in main database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, soap, token

I have one application with local database and main application with main database. Admin is adding users from main application, but those users need to login from application with local database. I don't know if I should have all users copied in my local database and provide authentication from local app or send request from local app with credentials to main app and receive authentication token in return.

Comment: Can you try to rephrase your question? It's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: I have main application with its own database and other app with its own local database. All data is stored in main database. I can make changes from local app and those changes will be applied to main database. Users are registered from main app and they are stored in main database. However, they can login from local app. Should I get all users from main database and store them in local  too and do all authentication there or could I send credentials for login from local to main app, authenticate there and send back authentication token to local app? I don't know if that has a sense at all.

Comment: You should authenticate in your "main database" and send the token back to the local application. As a general rule, you shouldn't authenticate logins client side. Also, data integrity will be a nightmare if you're trying to duplicate the records between databases.